# How to manage events on a specific div?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to catch some events for a specific div if the user clicked on the div (focus the div), keyboard events are catch (not if the last click was out of the div (unfocus the div)

I tried some things, but haven't succeeded : [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Qjwj/)

```
document.getElementById("box").onkeydown = function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) { // ENTER
        alert("Key ENTER pressed");
    }
}
```

This code doesn't work even if I click on the div.

**Pure JS solution please**

Comment: With [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) that would be a simple task. Simply do `$('#mydiv').on('keydown', function() { /*callback*/ });`

Comment: @Anticom jQuery isnt' tagged in this question.

Comment: @Anticom That makes no sense whatsoever `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: @PeeHaa you'd have to include the jq lib of course...

Comment: Well you say of course. I don't know that. Neither do I want to include some random library in my code to bind some event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving the 'div' a tabindex should do the trick, so the div can have the focus:

```
<div id="box" tabindex="-1"></div>
```

If you click on the div it gets the focus and you can catch the event.

[JSFIDDEL](http://jsfiddle.net/3Qjwj/8/)

If you set 'tabindex' > 0 you can also select the div using TAB.

Answer (score 3):

The `div` element isn't [*interactive content*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content) by default. This means that there isn't a case where the <kbd>return</kbd> key will ever trigger on it. If you want your `div` element to be interactive you can give it the `contenteditable` attribute:

```
<div id="box" contenteditable></div>
```

In order to now fire the event you need to first focus the `div` element (by clicking or tabbing into it). Now any key you press will be handled by your `onkeydown` event.

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Qjwj/4/).

Comment: How can I handle click `on` and `out` of the div to `show` or `hide` the div for example ?

Comment: @Elfayer That is a different question to the one you've asked here, so I suggest you start a new question or search the site for similar ones. Regardless you'd want to handle the `onmousedown` and `onmouseup` events in order to achieve this.

Comment: What's the difference between `contenteditable` and `tabindex` ? (It was on the question or @rednaw misread the post, anyway I edited the question, I'll ask another question for this)

Comment: `tabindex` specifies the order in which elements can be tabbed to (using the tab key on your keyboard) on a page. `contenteditable` allows elements to accept text input. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/tabindex and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable.

Answer (score 1):

You could catch all the click events, then check if the event target was inside the div:

```
var focus_on_div = false;

document.onclick = function(event) {
    if(event.target.getAttribute('id') == 'mydiv') {
        focus_on_div = true;
    } else { 
        focus_on_div = false;
    }
}

document.onkeyup = function(event) {
    if (focus_on_div) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code i hope this work

```
var mousePosition = {x:0, y:0};
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(mouseMoveEvent){
  mousePosition.x = mouseMoveEvent.pageX;
  mousePosition.y = mouseMoveEvent.pageY;
}, false);

window.onkeydown = function(event) {
    var x = mousePosition.x;
    var y = mousePosition.y;

    var elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
    if(elementMouseIsOver.id == "box" && event.keyCode == "13") {
        alert("You Hate Enter Dont You?");    
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3Qjwj/9/)